# Axios baseUrl on EC2, reference Ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, axios, next.js

I want to deploy an app on EC2 instance, but facing a problem with axios calls. Everything worked fine in a development environment because on localhost, however. Once I deployed this app onto EC2 instance, I face a problem of `POST http://localhost:3000/stop 0 ()` whenever I press on a stop button or anything else on the website.

The entire app developed with next.js and there I have installed axios which during development was configured to be

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
})

export default instance;
```

I know I need to change this baseURL to IP address provided by EC2, but how can I do so dynamically so that baseURL gets the current global IP address directly?

Or how should I approach this problem?

Comment: What is your question here? How can you get the IP of the EC2 or how can you dynmically set it in axios?

Comment: I think both, in simple terms. What should i put in my baseURL so that it doesnt give me that error and can perform  axios requests

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give you an example in JS exactly, but you can retrieve EC2 metadata information by requesting this : `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` . You can read up on what you can get from querying that endpoint here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval . In your case, you can add `local-ipv4` at the end of the endpoint above and you will get the Private IPv4 of the EC2 Instance. It is up to you to make it update dynamically.

Comment: that can work, but im afraid it will make my app way too static, isnt there a better way to solve this?

Comment: How would it make it static?

Comment: Im not sure it will work fine, if lets say i decide to add load balancing etc. It might point to just one instance all the time. There has to be a better way to do it, i've googled a few things about latest/meta-data and i dont see anyone mentioning or working like this with my type of projects:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181891/discussion-between-tenorflyy-and-stas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve EC2 metadata information by requesting this : http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ . You can read up on what you can get from querying that endpoint here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval . In your case, you can add local-ipv4 at the end of the endpoint above and you will get the Private IPv4 of the EC2 Instance